# Definition of Sathpurisha

Tags: sutras

What is the definition of "Sathpurisa/Sathpurusha" according to the Buddha?

Please provide sutta references.

Metta.

Comment: https://suttacentral.net/search?query=Sappurisa

Comment: @Dhammadhatu It gives a pali-english meaning. I actually need a sutta where the buddha defines who a sappurisa means.

Comment: You'll find some dhamma sermons in youtube.

Comment: there are many suttas at the link. regards

Answer (score 2):

How about the eponymous [Sappurisa Sutta (AN 4.73)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.073.than.html):

> "Now, a person endowed with these four qualities can be known as 'a
>   person of integrity.' Which four?
>
> "There is the case where a person of integrity, when asked, does not
>   reveal another person's bad points, to say nothing of when unasked.
>   Furthermore, when asked, when pressed with questions, he is one who
>   speaks of another person's bad points not in full, not in detail, with
>   omissions, holding back. Of this person you may know, 'This venerable
>   one is a person of integrity.'
>
> "Then again, a person of integrity, when unasked, reveals another
>   person's good points, to say nothing of when asked. Furthermore, when
>   asked, when pressed with questions, he is one who speaks of another
>   person's good points in full & in detail, without omissions, without
>   holding back. Of this person you may know, 'This venerable one is a
>   person of integrity.'
>
> "Then again, a person of integrity, when unasked, reveals his own bad
>   points, to say nothing of when asked. Furthermore, when asked, when
>   pressed with questions, he is one who speaks of his own bad points in
>   full & in detail, without omissions, without holding back. Of this
>   person you may know, 'This venerable one is a person of integrity.'
>
> "Then again, a person of integrity, when asked, does not reveal his
>   own good points, to say nothing of when unasked. Furthermore, when
>   asked, when pressed with questions, he is one who speaks of his own
>   good points not in full, not in detail, with omissions, holding back.
>   Of this person you may know, 'This venerable one is a person of
>   integrity.'
>
> "Monks, a person endowed with these four qualities can be known as 'a
>   person of integrity.'"

And also the eponymous [Sappurisa Sutta (MN 113)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.113.than.html):

> "But a person of integrity notices, 'It's not through having a
>   high-ranking family that the quality of greed goes to its end; it's
>   not through having a high-ranking family that the quality of
>   aversion... the quality of delusion goes to its end. Even though one
>   has not gone forth from a high-ranking family, if — practicing the
>   Dhamma in line with the Dhamma, practicing masterfully — he is one who
>   follows the Dhamma, he is to be honored for that, praised for that.'
>   So, giving priority just to the practice, he neither exalts himself
>   for having a high-ranking family nor disparages others. This is the
>   quality of a person of integrity.
>
> "But a person of integrity notices, 'It's not through having a family
>   of extensive wealth that the quality of greed goes to its end; it's
>   not through having a family of extensive wealth that the quality of
>   aversion... the quality of delusion goes to its end. Even though one
>   has not gone forth from a family of extensive wealth, if — practicing
>   the Dhamma in line with the Dhamma, practicing masterfully — he is one
>   who follows the Dhamma, he is to be honored for that, praised for
>   that.' So, giving priority just to the practice, he neither exalts
>   himself for having a family of extensive wealth nor disparages others.
>   This is the quality of a person of integrity.
>
> "But a person of integrity notices, 'It's not through being well-known
>   & highly regarded that the quality of greed goes to its end; it's not
>   through being well-known & highly regarded that the quality of
>   aversion... the quality of delusion goes to its end. Even though one
>   is not well-known & highly regarded, if — practicing the Dhamma in
>   line with the Dhamma, practicing masterfully — he is one who follows
>   the Dhamma, he is to be honored for that, praised for that.' So,
>   giving priority just to the practice, he neither exalts himself for
>   being well-known nor disparages others. This is the quality of a
>   person of integrity.
>
> "But a person of integrity notices, 'It's not through gains that the
>   quality of greed goes to its end; it's not through gains that the
>   quality of aversion... the quality of delusion goes to its end. Even
>   though one is not one who gains robe-cloth, alms-food, lodgings, &
>   medicinal requisites for the sick, if — practicing the Dhamma in line
>   with the Dhamma, practicing masterfully — he is one who follows the
>   Dhamma, he is to be honored for that, praised for that.' So, giving
>   priority just to the practice, he neither exalts himself for his gains
>   nor disparages others. This is the quality of a person of integrity.
>
> "But a person of integrity notices, 'It's not through being a
>   Dhamma-speaker that the quality of greed goes to its end; it's not
>   through being a Dhamma-speaker that the quality of aversion... the
>   quality of delusion goes to its end. Even though one is not a
>   Dhamma-speaker, if — practicing the Dhamma in line with the Dhamma,
>   practicing masterfully — he is one who follows the Dhamma, he is to be
>   honored for that, praised for that.' So, giving priority just to the
>   practice, he neither exalts himself for being a Dhamma-speaker nor
>   disparages others. This is the quality of a person of integrity.
>
> "But a person of integrity notices, 'It's not through being a
>   wilderness dweller that the quality of greed goes to its end; it's not
>   through being a wilderness dweller that the quality of aversion... the
>   quality of delusion goes to its end. Even though one is not a
>   wilderness dweller, if — practicing the Dhamma in line with the
>   Dhamma, practicing masterfully — he is one who follows the Dhamma, he
>   is to be honored for that, praised for that.' So, giving priority just
>   to the practice, he neither exalts himself for being a wilderness
>   dweller nor disparages others. This is the quality of a person of
>   integrity.
>
> "But a person of integrity notices, 'It's not through being one who
>   eats only one meal a day that the quality of greed goes to its end;
>   it's not through being one who eats only one meal a day that the
>   quality of aversion... the quality of delusion goes to its end. Even
>   though one is not one who eats only one meal a day, if — practicing
>   the Dhamma in line with the Dhamma, practicing masterfully — he is one
>   who follows the Dhamma, he is to be honored for that, praised for
>   that.' So, giving priority just to the practice, he neither exalts
>   himself for being one who eats only one meal a day nor disparages
>   others. This is the quality of a person of integrity.
>
> "But a person of integrity notices, 'The Blessed One has spoken of
>   non-fashioning even with regard to the attainment of the first jhāna,
>   for by whatever means they construe it, it becomes otherwise from
>   that.'  So, giving priority to non-fashioning, he neither exalts
>   himself for the attainment of the first jhāna nor disparages others.
>   This is the quality of a person of integrity.
>
> "A person of integrity notices, 'The Blessed One has spoken of
>   non-fashioning even with regard to the attainment of the dimension of
>   neither perception nor non-perception, for by whatever means they
>   construe it, it becomes otherwise from that.' So, giving priority to
>   non-fashioning, he neither exalts himself for the attainment of the
>   dimension of neither perception nor non-perception nor disparages
>   others. This is the quality of a person of integrity.
>
> "A person of integrity, completely transcending the dimension of
>   neither perception nor non-perception, enters & remains in the
>   cessation of feeling & perception. When he sees with discernment, his
>   effluents are ended. This is a monk who does not construe anything,
>   does not construe anywhere, does not construe in any way."